# Query using http post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

As I used app.get to query in urls as localhost:3000/data?country=Italy and I get the data stored in MongoDb. How can I use app.post request method to query the parameters and get the data? I'm unable to find the proper solution and I'm completely new to this.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/source_scrapped_data";
const app = express();
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
// mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log("Connected to mongo");
});
const covid_data = mongoose.model('Covid',
    new Schema({}),
    'covid_data');
app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    const continent = req.query.continent;
    const country = req.query.country;
    covid_data.find({'Continent':continent,'Country':country},(err,docs)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.send("no data found",err)
        }
        else{
            console.log(err)
            res.send(docs)
        }
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: `POSTt` is used to send data to the server whereas `GET` is used to get data from the server. So, while returning from the server use `GET` request not `POST`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/data", (req, res) => {
    const continent = req.body.continent;
    const country = req.body.country;
    covid_data.find({'Continent':continent,'Country':country},(err,docs)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.send("no data found",err)
        }
        else{
            console.log(err)
            res.send(docs)
        }
    });
});
```

This is how you can get data in post request that is passed in the body of the request.

- This is not the standard practice you should not use post request to do get a query. Always use POST method to put some data in the database.

Comment: while running url: localhost:3000/data?country=India gives Cannot GET /post_data...insttead of giving me the complete data....can you please guide me for this....im doing just for learning on ho to work with post ...would be a really big help

Comment: You can use tools like postman to test the api. Because i think you are trying Get request with post data.